# Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "android:name"

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to design my Android.Manifest file for GCM but I found an error in my program it said "open quote is expected for attribute "

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    <category android:name="com.example.googlecloudmessaging"/>
</intent-filter>"
```

associated with an element type

Comment: Please post the manifest file.

Comment: `android:name="Something"` It seems you are missing a quote (or both).